# Program printing to zebra printer ZPL? or alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

Is printing as RAW using ZPL the best way to print contents via zebra printers?

What are the best alternatives to using ZPL string? Can I use the ZebraDesigner Driver? If so, what is the way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with ZPL (only EPL), but I believe that's similar enough to answer your question.

From my experience with Zebra printers and EPL (more than 10 years), sending the raw EPL commands to the printer **is** the most robust/most reliable way.
For a more detailed opinion, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880152/6884) to a similar question which I wrote a few years ago.

---

To get started with printing to Zebra printers from C#, I can recommend these two blog posts by [Nicholas Piasecki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32187/nicholas-piasecki) *(links are going to the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/) since [his website](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog) seems to be dead)*:

- [Sending Raw EPL2 Directly to a Zebra LP2844 via C#](http://web.archive.org/web/20140922053236/http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c)
- [Using the EPL2 GW command to send an image to a Zebra thermal printer](http://web.archive.org/web/20141109172303/http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2013/02/using-the-epl2-gw-command/)